# Sqlite Query based on Alternate Rows and Count of Columns

Tags: sqlite

I am new to Sqlite Db and i have table with following records

```
|AutoID   |Data|Date|
-+-------------+----------
|1            |A   |7-1-2014        
|2            |A   |7-1-2014     
|3            |B   |7-1-2014      
|4            |C   |7-1-2014   
|5            |B   |7-1-2014     
|6            |A   |7-1-2014
```

I must Ensure that Every Data[Column] is served equally,i.e if Data [Column] contains(A,A,B,C,B,A) it must behave like a queue and the Column must be like(A,B,C,A,B,A).

**Note:An Order is maintained after rearranging**.

So my select query should produce the following output

Excepted Output:

```
|AutoID   |Data|Date|
-+-------------+----------
|1            |A   |7-1-2014        
|3            |B   |7-1-2014     
|4            |C   |7-1-2014      
|2            |A   |7-1-2014   
|5            |B   |7-1-2014     
|6            |A   |7-1-2014
```

We have Partition in Sql Server,and the same output can be produced, Since Sqlite does not have partition,i am looking if i can achieve the same with select queries.

So Far i have grouped the table based on Data[Column] and it produces the following output.

> Select * from Sample group by Data;

```
|AutoID   |Data|Date|
-+-------------+----------
|1            |A   |7-1-2014        
|2            |A   |7-1-2014     
|6            |A   |7-1-2014      
|3            |B   |7-1-2014   
|5            |B   |7-1-2014     
|4            |C   |7-1-2014
```

Could i know how to write a query on top of the above statement and produce the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the first occurrences of each `Data` value, then all the second ones, and so on.

To compute which occurrence a particular record is, use a correlated subquery to count how many previous records with the same `Data` value there are:

```
SELECT Data,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Sample AS S2
        WHERE S2.Data   = Sample.Data
          AND S2.AutoID < Sample.AutoID
       ) AS Nr
FROM Sample
```

```
Data | Nr
---------
 A   | 0
 A   | 1
 B   | 0
 C   | 0
 B   | 1
 A   | 2
```

This computed valued can then be used to sort the output:

```
SELECT AutoID,
       Data,
       Date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Sample AS S2
        WHERE S2.Data   = Sample.Data
          AND S2.AutoID < Sample.AutoID
       ) AS Nr
FROM Sample
ORDER BY Nr, Data
```

Comment: You made the problem very simple!Great Explanation.TX!